# ms-access: check if font color is white

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

in conditional formatting what would be the expression i would use to check whether a DIFFERENT textbox's font color is set to white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With VBA, you can check whether a control's ForeColor property is white (vbWhite = 16777215).

```
If Me!SomeControl.Properties("ForeColor") = 16777215 Then
```

However, I'm lost trying to figure out how to apply that approach in conditional formatting.

Comment: Yeah, I understood.  My head exploded trying to work it into conditional formatting.  Sorry.

Comment: I'd recommend finding some other way around the issue.  Like, what is the criteria for the other field's forecolor? Can you base your formatting off that?

Comment: Would you not just use the same test that causes the other control to be rendered as white?